# create dataset from one column csv file where data are separated by spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with one column, I want to split this column to many columns so I get a real dataset

```
data
02/01/19         11 725001                   ADWYA                     4,7          4,7        4,8           4,8        4,8        4,8        4,8              4296          5    20620,8                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 340005                   AMEN BANK                27,8         27,8       27,8         27,75      27,75       27,5       27,8               261          9    7240,06                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 730001                   ARTES                    6,27         6,27       6,27          6,28       6,28       6,27       6,29              2532          4   15924,09                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 714001                   ASSAD                    7,79          7,8       7,79          8,02       8,02       7,78       8,02             14878         62  118592,33                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 360035                   ATB                      3,76         3,66       3,76          3,65       3,65       3,65       3,87               533         13    1948,72                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 774001                   ATELIER MEUBLE INT       4,18         4,18       4,18           4,2        4,2       4,15        4,2               848          8    3530,24                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 470010                   ATL                      2,69         2,69       2,65          2,63       2,63       2,61       2,65              3403         11    9005,19                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 160015                   ATTIJARI BANK              41           41       41,9            41         41         41         42              9242         44  379252,01                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 661001                   ATTIJARI LEASING        16,59        16,59       16,1          16,1       16,1       16,1       16,1               366          9     5892,6
```

The separation between data in each row is specific number of `spaces`
So I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = df.data.str.split('         ').str[0]
df['rest1'] = df.data.str.split('         ').str[-1]
```

but didn't work.

Expected output:

```
date             c1 c2                       c3                        c4   ...  
02/01/19         11 725001                   ADWYA                     4,7          4,7        4,8           4,8        4,8        4,8        4,8              4296          5    20620,8                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 340005                   AMEN BANK                27,8         27,8       27,8         27,75      27,75       27,5       27,8               261          9    7240,06                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 730001                   ARTES                    6,27         6,27       6,27          6,28       6,28       6,27       6,29              2532          4   15924,09                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 714001                   ASSAD                    7,79          7,8       7,79          8,02       8,02       7,78       8,02             14878         62  118592,33                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 360035                   ATB                      3,76         3,66       3,76          3,65       3,65       3,65       3,87               533         13    1948,72                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 774001                   ATELIER MEUBLE INT       4,18         4,18       4,18           4,2        4,2       4,15        4,2               848          8    3530,24                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 470010                   ATL                      2,69         2,69       2,65          2,63       2,63       2,61       2,65              3403         11    9005,19                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 160015                   ATTIJARI BANK              41           41       41,9            41         41         41         42              9242         44  379252,01                                                                                                                   
02/01/19         11 661001                   ATTIJARI LEASING        16,59        16,59       16,1          16,1       16,1       16,1       16,1               366          9     5892,6                                                                                                                   
#c1, c2, c3.. are columns names
#data on c3 may contains 1 space
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas support regex split, `\s+` will match 1 or more spaces and split on it:

```
df['data'].str.split(r'\s+')
```

Comment: we can match 2 or more space and split on it ? (instead of 1 or more)

Comment: Yeah then use `r'\s{2,}'`